# Realizar o reshape de arrays diferentes

Tags: python, numpy

Olá!

Segue abaixo minha dúvida:

```
array_a = [1,2,3]
array_b = [1,2,3]
array_c = [1,2,3]
```

Eu gostaria que eles ficassem da seguinte forma:

```
array_reshaped = 
  [[1, 1, 1],
   [2, 2, 2],
   [3, 3, 3]]
```

Teria como eu realizar essa operação em `python` utilizando o `numpy.reshape`?

Comment: Não basta apenas calcular a matriz transposta?

Comment: O *zip* sozinho não serve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que você precisa é a matriz transposta, não um *reshape*.

```py
>>> matrix = numpy.matrix(
...   [[1, 2, 3],
...    [1, 2, 3],
...    [1, 2, 3]]
... )
```

Para obter a matriz transposta basta fazer `matriz.T`:

```py
>>> print(matrix.T)
[[1 1 1]
 [2 2 2]
 [3 3 3]]
```

Se for usar NumPy somente para isso, esqueça. Como comentado, a própria função `zip` já resolve o problema:

```py
result = [lista for lista in zip(array_a, array_b, array_c)]
```

Comment: Muitissimo obrigado cara, me ajudou bastante.